# How to get Manufacturer dropdown in custom module edit form?

Tags: magento-1.8

I want to add images for each brand, for that i have created a module. in module's edit form i want a manufacturer dropdown list so i can assign image to the particular manufacturer/brand.

its my code for the edit form location:

`app/code/local/Root/Brand/Block/Adminhtml/Brand/Edit/Tab/form.php`

```
$fieldset->addField('title', 'select', array('name' => 'title', 'label' => 'Brand', 'values' => Mage::getUrl('catalogsearch/advanced/result', array('brand'=>$option['value'])), )); $fieldset->addField('filename', 'image', array( 'label' => Mage::helper('brand')->__('Brand Image'), 'required' => false, 'name' => 'filename', 'note' => '(*.jpg, *.png, *.gif)', ));
```

Comment: please more details of your module

Comment: put your code Otherwise we cannot help u

Comment: @piyush Next time edit the question instead of putting the code in comments now I done that for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'manufacturer');
             //here, "brandname" is the attribute_code
         $allOptions = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true);
         $fieldset->addField('title', 'select', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('brand')->__('Brand Name'),
          'name'    => 'title',
          'values'   => $allOptions
      ));
```